# Saddle point method and radius of convergence

Tags: statistics, statistical-mechanics, large-deviation-theory

I have a question concerning the convergence of the saddle point method. Applying the method to a function $\rho(x)$, defined as

\begin{align}
\rho(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int dk\, e^{\kappa f(k,\sigma)}, 
\end{align}

is it possible to determine a radius of convergence in terms of the function $f(k,\sigma)$ so that the asymptotic result

\begin{align}
\rho(x) \underset{\kappa \to \infty}{\sim} e^{\kappa F(x,\sigma)}
\end{align}

always holds? My goal is to set bounds to $\sigma$ indirectly, which is just a real parameter that appears in both functions $F(x,\sigma)$ and $f(k,\sigma)$, up to which $\sigma$ can be varied, without affecting the method. I took a look in large deviation theory, but nothing crossed my path that could shed any light on my problem.

Comment: The concept here is "uniform asymptotic expansion" and unfortunately there is no systematic way to get one.

Comment: So you like to have an asymptotics for $\rho(x,\kappa,\sigma)$ as $\kappa\to \infty$ uniformly in $x$?

Comment: I would like to see how this asymptotic method converges in terms of $\sigma$. I  guess one can not infinitely increase the value of $\sigma$ without affecting the saddle point approach. It must be upper bound to that parameter above which one can no longer vary it, right?